# String Partial Search in sql

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom User Checked');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy Admin Done');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank Marry Ali');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'Jane Go to Date');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,'Robert Use Only PIN');
COMMIT;
```

```sql
/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM NAMES;
```

I want To find Data NAMES With 'Tom Checked' ,

I want To find Data NAMES With 'Lucy Done' ,

I want To find Data NAMES With 'Frank Ali' , etc

Only How Can I use Query In sql like operator Or Any other method

thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Is your search item always the first and the last word of a value in your table? i.e. 'Frank Marry Ali', and your example is find 'Frank Ali'.. Should a search for  'Frank Marry' also match?

Comment: maria db i have used in invirnment of php mysql

Comment: What are the table column names?

Comment: I am a bit lost.  You seem to be describing a condition where you want to find all rows.  Do you want to find one at a time?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the like operator, for the 'Tom Checked' example you can use the below code

```sql
SELECT * FROM NAMES where NAMES like '%Tom%' and NAMES like '%Checked%'
```

Comment: The fieldname in the table `NAMES` should be `NAMES` for this to work.

Comment: yeah that's what i assumed

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to use a like operator:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%Tom%' and ColumnName LIKE '%Checked%'
```

Comment: Note that `'%Tom%'` will also find `Tompkins`.

Comment: Question says: `I want To find Data NAMES With 'Tom Checked'`

Comment: My answer was more just to show the LIKE operate but you are both right so have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mysql/mssql/access or similar you have:

```
select * from [NAMES] where [name] like '%Tom User Checked%
```

to filter out name strings including 'Tom User Checked'

```
 select * from [NAMES] where [name] like '%Jane'
```

to filter out name strings start with 'Jane'

```
 select * from [NAMES] where [name] like 'Only PIN%'
```

to filter out name strings end with 'Only PIN'

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use stored procedure for dynamic Search

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- usp_GetReportInfo 3,17,65

Create PROC [dbo].[usp_SeahcByName]
@name nvarchar
AS BEGIN


   SELECT   *
FROM            NAMES
WHERE        (NAMES LIKE '%name%')
END

then Just Execute this Store Procedure With Value
EXEC usp_SeahcByName
```

Or You can use Raw query Like

```
SELECT   * FROM NAMES WHERE        (NAMES LIKE '%Tom Checked%')
```